# Is it possible to find the value of x in python? i.e asking python to solve an equation such as 2x + 23 - 7x when x is not a pre-defined variable

Tags: python, math, eval, equation, equation-solving

What I want is a program that can determine the value of `x` from an equation when `x` is not yet defined i.e. not a python variable.
Just an example below, not the real thing.

```
sol = eval("input please type the equation: ")
#i.e sol = 32x - 40
print(sol)
```

Comment: Do you want to solve an equation, or simplify an expression?

Comment: Equations have equal signs. `2x+23-7x` is an expression.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any built in way to do that but `Sympy` library is built exactly for this stuff. Solvers module in Sympy can be used to solve linear equations. [(Here)](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) is a link to its docs.

Answer (score 1):

An explicit example using [`sympy`](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import x

print sympy.solve(32*x-40,"x")
print sympy.solve(2*x+23-7*x,"x")
```

Gives as output:

```
[5/4]
[23/5]
```

Note that there is the separate question of parsing user input. That is, how do we take the string "32x-40" and turn it into the expression `32*x-40`. This can be a non-trivial task depending on the complexity of the equations you are looking to model. If you are insterested in that, I would look into [`pyparsing`](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use sympy. Then you can do it in the print command. It looks like this.

```
import sympy 
from sympy.abc import x
print sympy.solve(nub1*x+nub2-nub3*x,"Whatever you want here.")
```